# How to get average of multiple variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table name: `products`,

column names: `rice_price`, `sugar_price`

I would like to get the average of both columns separately. For example;

```
SELECT
  AVG(rice_price) avg_rice,
  AVG(sugar_price) avg_sugar
FROM
  products
```

If I run this query on SQL server, I get the message below

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for avg operator.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Convert your string to a number? Why are you storing numbers as a string anyway? You should really correct your schema.

Comment: Also why would a "Products" table have columns for `rice_price` and `sugar_price`?

Comment: To expand on @MartinSmith's comment, the name of your columns suggest you have a denormalised design. You should have a column with the product's name  and a column for the price and then you have 1 tow per product, not separate columns for each product. The fact your want an average, suggests that you probably should also have a separate table for what ever the need for the many relationship you have is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If most of them look like numbers, you could use this, which will exclude the ones that don't convert nicely, by handling them as null:

```
SELECT
  AVG(try_convert(numeric(18,4),rice_price)) avg_rice,
  AVG(try_convert(numeric(18,4),sugar_price)) avg_sugar
FROM
  products
```

But you should be changing your datatypes as has been pointed out in the comments. This kind of query will help you discover the ones that aren't good.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE rice_price IS NOT NULL
AND try_convert(numeric(18,4),rice_price) IS NULL

SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE sugar_price IS NOT NULL
AND try_convert(numeric(18,4),sugar_price) IS NULL
```

The `IS_NUMERIC` function can work for this too, but I find I have switched to using `TRY_CONVERT` in this situation, because it feels more flexible - I can use whatever data type I need.

Comment: thanx for your solution. Actually, my data type was nvarchar, and I wasn't aware of this. However, I've learned another interesting way to work with this kind of problem from your solution and I liked it.